# Validate causes error during Uploading iphone application

Tags: iphone

I am trying to upload an iphone application.In the last step I created an archive file and it also available in the organizer window.But when l clicks validate button it shows error.
 "My Application does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application."

In my application have no static libraries .

Please give me a solution...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the Build Settings, set the "Skip Install" to "Yes" and then
Under the Build Phases, examine the Copy Headers section. If there are any header files listed as Private or Public, drag them down to the Project section.

Comment: Actually I done the first settings and tried but the same error occurs. But I cant see the second setting(Under the Build Phases, examine he Copy Headers section).So I am totally confused please give me another solution.

Comment: Make sure you’re using a release version of Xcode, beta versions won’t archive as well. If you still have problems, you can always do a brute force method of taking your build folder (right-click on the product.app and choose “reveal in finder”), renaming the entire directory “Payload”, zip it up and change the suffix to .ipa. Voila, there’s your archive. Good luck!!

Comment: more over see these links and read all the dicsussion http://flakasoft.com/developer-tips/xcode-4-bug-solution-for-archiving-build-with-static-library/